# How To insert an image at cursor position in tinymce

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I am using following codes to fetch the conent of tinymce.

```
tinymce_content=tinyMCE.get('txt_area_id').getContent();
updated_content=tinymce_content+"<img src="sample.jpg">";
```

By using above codes i am inserting image inside tinymce content.

**Question:** How to insert image in the cursor position inside tinymce (ie) How to predict cursor position and split the content to insert image between fetched content.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This will insert an image node at the selected spot (cursor position) in a tinymce editor

```
var ed = tinyMCE.get('txt_area_id');                // get editor instance
var range = ed.selection.getRng();                  // get range
var newNode = ed.getDoc().createElement ( "img" );  // create img node
newNode.src="sample.jpg";                           // add src attribute
range.insertNode(newNode);                          // insert Node
```

Comment: Great, whenever i felt struggle in tinymce, i remember thariama Thank u

Comment: glad to have been able to help

Comment: Just to make this already awesome post a little more clear... To refresh the image and make sure it renders correctly you must make sure that your creating the element in tinyMCE's DOM not the window DOM. So if your using `createElement` make sure you do something like `opener.tinyMCE.selectedInstance.getDoc().createElement`.

Comment: and that is exactly the same as ed.getDoc().createElement

Comment: Hi Man, I have added a question linked to your answer. Can you please give me comments. Here is the question. [How to add style attribute to an image added with selection.getRng(); in TinyMCE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33960835/how-to-add-style-attribute-to-an-image-added-with-selection-getrng-in-tinymce)

Answer (score 10):

[@Thariama's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192134/how-to-insert-an-image-at-cursor-position-in-tinymce/5193042#5193042) worked fine for me in Chrome, but not in IE.  I had to modify it to the following to get it to work in both browsers:

```
var ed = tinyMCE.get('txt_area_id');                // get editor instance
var newNode = ed.getDoc().createElement ( "img" );  // create img node
newNode.src="sample.jpg";                           // add src attribute
ed.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, newNode.outerHTML)
```

(IE was telling me that `range` did not have an `insertNode` method.)

Comment: Both solutions dont work for me. My IE says: "SCRIPT16389: Erro não especificado." wich means "Error not specified in english... Using IE9 and  tiny 3.4

Comment: I am using tinymce 4.0 .                                                     It is working fine in IE10, but getting following error in IE11       SCRIPT16389: Incorrect function.
File: tinymce.min.js, Line: 8, Column: 20915  Can you please help me out.