# How to add style attribute to an image added with getDoc().createElement( "img" ); in TinyMCE

Tags: jquery, tinymce-4

[How To insert an image at cursor position in tinymce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192134/how-to-insert-an-image-at-cursor-position-in-tinymce)

From the above mentioned question I manage to add an Image in TinyMCE.

```
var ed = tinyMCE.get('txt_area_id');                // get editor instance
var range = ed.selection.getRng();                  // get range
var newNode = ed.getDoc().createElement ( "img" );  // create img node
newNode.src="sample.jpg";                           // add src attribute
range.insertNode(newNode);                          // insert Node
```

I am trying to add the width to `newNode` with this code:

```
 newNode.style = "width:600px;"; // not working
```

but its not working, same goes for class I cannot add a class via this code:

```
newNode.class= "myClass"; // this one is also not working
```

If any one have some idea please let me know thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
newNode.style = "width:600px;";
```

You're accessing the node's style object, rather than the style attribute. So, you can either update, or set, the style object:

```
newNode.style.width = "600px;";
```

Or update, or set, the style attribute:

```
newNode.setAttribute("style", "width:600px");
```

Note that, in the latter example, any existing values held in the style attribute will be overwritten with the new string; to update only one property value you should use the former example, and target specific properties of the style object.

To update the classes of an element:

```
newNode.className = "newClassName";
```

Or:

```
newNode.classList.add("newClassName");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot David :)

Comment: You're very welcome indeed, I'm glad to have helped!