# How to insert a button in TinyMCE Editor to insert a local file as RAW image at current position?

Tags: tinymce

How can i add a custom/default button to the TinyMCE Editor, to be able to select a local image and insert it as RAW (BASE64) image at current position in editor?

Comment: What have you tried? Steps would seem to be: a) Add a button; b) Cause button to drive 'upload file' sequence; c) send file to server; d) retrieve base64 version from server and insert into active Editor.

Comment: I habe no idea hownto implement it and why sending to server? Can TinyMCE or JS not convert it client side?

Comment: there's plenty existing documentation on tinymce buttons. As for sending to server, the issue is YOU can't read the file locally. You can send the file to a webserver, though.

Comment: I have no chance to store the image on the server or send it to an webservice to convert it to raw.

Comment: Then look into javascript File API. It will let you read it in most clients. You'll get the file object (a Blob). Pass that into the File API `readAsArrayBuffer()`, and on load stuff back into tinymce. Yes, I'm doing some hand-waving, but that should get you started. I suggest you try first without tinymce to get the File stuff working & then integrate.

Answer (score 2):

I just tried this from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36281449).

```js
window.onload = function () {
  document.getElementById("fileName").onchange = function () {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    reader.onload = function () {
      console.log(reader.result);
      document.getElementById("img").src = reader.result;
    };
    reader.onerror = function (error) {
      console.log('Error: ', error);
    };
  };
};
```

```html
<input type="file" name="fileName" id="fileName" /><br />
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/250x75/000/fff.png&text=Select+an+Image" id="img" style="max-width: 250px; max-height: 75px;" />
```

Using the above URL (see console or inspect element and find the `src`) and with [inserting an image at the current position](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5193042), you can insert the image inside the document at the current position of caret.